# Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform, harmonic-functions, laplace-method

Hello how can I solve this problem $ty''-y'=t^2$, $y (0)=0 $

I though about several ways like  $y''-y'/t =t$ but I did not know how to solve the integral of $( y'/t) $.

Then I thought about  integration  of $y''t$ which $= ty'-y+C$ but then I reach to $ty'-y+C=y+t^3/3$   but then what?

Comment: Mathematical formulae look better in $\LaTeX$. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) is a quick tutorial.

Comment: What's the connection with Laplace ?

Answer (score 1):

Do we need to use a laplace transform?

$t y'' -y' = t^2\\
v = y', v' = y''\\
tv' - v = t^2\\
v' - (1/t) v = t\\
e^{\int \frac{-1}{t} dt} = \frac{1}{t}\\
\frac{1}{t}v' - \frac{1}{t^2}v = 1\\
\frac{1}{t}y' = t + c
$

And I will let you take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the Laplace transform, and  counting that  $  \mathcal{L}\{y'\} = sY(s)-y(0)$ and $\mathcal{L}\{y''\} = s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)$, where $Y(s) = \mathcal{L}\{y(t)\}(s).$

\begin{gather*}
\mathcal{L}\{ty''\} - \mathcal{L}\{y'\} = \mathcal{L}\{t^2\} \\
-\frac{d}{ds}(s^2Y -sy(0) - y'(0)) - sY +y(0) = \frac{2!}{s^3}\\
-(2sY + s^2Y)-sY = \frac{2}{s^3} \\
Y(s^2 - 3s) = \frac{2}{s^3} \\
Y= \frac{2}{s^4(s-3)}
\end{gather*}

Now, apply the Inverse Laplace Transform and looking the convolution product

\begin{align*}
y &= 2 \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{ \frac{1}{s^4}\frac{1}{s-3} \} \\
  &= 2( \frac{t^3}{3!} * e^{3t}) \\
  &= \frac{1}{3} [  \int_0^t \Gamma^3e^{3(t-\Gamma)}d\Gamma] \\
  &= \frac{1}{81}[2e^{3t} -9t^3 -9t^2 - 6t -2] 
\end{align*}

I think is correct the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the substitution $y'=u$ so that $u'-\frac{u}{t}=t$ and dividing by $t$
$$
\frac{u'}{t}-\frac{u}{t^2}=1
$$
or
$$
\left(\frac{u}{t}\right)'=1\quad \Longrightarrow\;\frac{u}{t}=t+A
$$
and then $$u(t)=t^2+At$$ So from $y'=u$ you'll have
$$
y(t)=\int u\mathrm dt=\frac{t^3}{3}+At^2+B
$$
From $y(0)=0$, we have $B=0$
$$
y(t)=\frac{t^3}{3}+At^2
$$
To find $A$ you need another extra condition.

Comment: I will  thanks for  helping

Comment: AM still stuck  can you show me your solution